# Amazon products don't show up in iframes

Tags: iframe

I'm trying to embed the amazon store via iframes into my website.

It works fine except when I click on any products, the product is not displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried out your link in Chrome and saw the following error when clicking on one of the products:

`Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

The amazon product details page request returns the following response header:

`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`

Based on the ["X-Frame-Options response header definition"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header), this means that "The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.". Amazon probably enforces this to prevent from [Clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).

Answer (score 14):

## Adblock

Adblock needs to be disabled.

(So if you put the frame on your site - put a note telling geeks to disable it or use incognito mode)

Answer (score 0):

In my case was [Avira](https://www.avira.com) who was blocking the ads.

[image]